# Problem with importing featherlightGallery

Tags: featherlight.js

I imported featherlight like so:

```
import featherlight from 'featherlight';
```

and this works, but when I try to do the same with featherlightGallery:

```
import featherlightGallery from 'featherlight';
```

or

```
import { featherlight, featherlightGallery } from 'featherlight';
```

I get:

```
$(...).featherlightGallery is not a function
```

I looked it up but featherlightGallery is UDM: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/pull/377#issuecomment-455854609

Comment: I'm sorry you're having troubles. I'm not actually familiar with importing it this way (is that in the browser? IE doesn't support import) so I'm not sure how to test this . Is it possible that both `featherlight` and `featherlightGallery` are getting a different value for `$`? Feel free to file a bug report if you prefer.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune This way if importing is used to import npm packages into a single .js file which is then compiled by, in my case, Webpack. Example: https://imgur.com/a/q7bK8w5